# Using QgsDxfExport in Python script leads to crash

Tags: qgis, python, error, pyqgis-3, dxf

I am trying to export a `QgsDxfLayer` from `QgsVectorLayer`, but it crashes at `dxf.addLayers()`.
Might I forget something essential ?

```py
...
dxfLayers = []
dxfLayers.append(QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(vecLayer, -1))

dxf = QgsDxfExport()

# Crashes here :-(
dxf.addLayers(dxfLayers)
```

I am using QGIS 3.8.

Here is a little bit more code

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():


    if layer.name() not in LAYERS_OF_INTEREST:
        continue

    info("------- '" + layer.name() + "' ------------------------")


    dxfLayers = []

    # Iterate through all layer features, create vector layer
    # new (vector-)layername, make a vector layer
    # instance and add it to layerList ..
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        try:
            # Create our own VectorLayer from feature,
            # make a DXFLayer from it and add it to dxfLayers[]
            vecLayer = MyVectorLayer(feature)
            dxfLayer = QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(vecLayer.layer, -1)
            dxfLayers.append(dxfLayer)

            if STORE_LAYERS_AS_SHAPEFILES:
                vecLayer.write2File(STORAGE_PATH)

        except Exception as e:
            notHandled += 1
            #print(str(e))
            pass

    if len(dxfLayers) > 0:
        # We have some dxf-layers in our list, so lets create
        # a QgsDxfExport instance and write the dxf-file to disk

        info(". Exporting dxf ...")

        dxf = QgsDxfExport()
        # I don't know why, but it
        # crashes here (FIXME)
        dxf.addLayers(dxfLayers)
        info(". ok 1")

        dxf.setDestinationCrs(layer.crs())
        info(". ok 2")

        # Export Dxf file
        dxfPath = STORAGE_PATH + "/" + layer.name() + ".dxf"
        info("  path '" + dxfPath + "'")
        dxfFile = QFile(dxfPath)
        dxfFile.open(QFile.ReadWrite)
        info(". ok 3")
        dxf.writeToFile(dxfFile,"UTF-8")
        dxfFile.close()
        info(". ok 4")
        exported += 1

info(". DONE, exported=" + str(exported) + " unknown=" + str(notHandled))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a definitive answer. More an answer to sort out minimum use case that works. To do this, I've tried with the following (simplified example from code mainly borrowed from [QgsDxfExport not exporting all features of a layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318592/qgsdxfexport-not-exporting-all-features-of-a-layer)) without any crash. I've also tried without using `setDestinationCrs` and `setExtent` without issue (PS: QGIS 3.10 target not 3.8 FYI)

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
dxfLayer = QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(layer)

dxfExport = QgsDxfExport()
dxfExport.setDestinationCrs(canvas.mapSettings().destinationCrs())
dxfExport.setExtent(canvas.extent())
dxfExport.addLayers([dxfLayer])

f = QFile('/tmp/demo.dxf')
f.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
dxfExport.writeToFile(f, "iso-8859-1")
f.close()
```